# ¿Cómo funciona la sentencia raiserror en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

He estado buscando información acerca de la palabra reservada "raiserror" en SQL, sin mucho éxito.

¿Alguien podría explicarme cómo funciona? Sobre todo tengo duda en los parámetros que deben utilizarse dentro de ésta sentencia.

Ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**RAISERROR** es una palabra reservada en SQL SERVER como lo son el resto de tipos definidos y métodos, para garantizar la gramática del lenguaje Transact-SQL que utiliza SQL SERVER.

El método `RAISERROR` genera un mensaje de error. Se puede emplear con un mensaje del catálogo 'sys.messages' o puedes generar un mensaje personalizado. El mensaje se devuelve como un mensaje de error de servidor a la aplicación que realiza la llamada o a un bloque `CATCH`.

A partir de SQL SERVER 2012 se recomienza el uso de `THROW`

El uso más común es el siguiente.

**Ejemplo de uso**

```
-- Mensaje simple

RAISERROR (
           N'This is a message.', -- Mensaje de ejemplo
           10, -- Severity,  
           1   -- State
);
-- DEVUELVE: This is a message.  
GO  

-- Mensaje con parámetros

RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.', -- Mensaje de ejemplo 
           10, -- Severity,  
           1, -- State,  
           N'number', -- Primer argumento 
           5          -- Segundo argumento
           --,N...    -- Más argumentos
); 
-- DEVUELVE: This is message number 5.  
GO
```

Dentro de `TRY ... CATCH`

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- RAISERROR con 'severity' 11-19 para causar la ejecución de bloque CATCH  
    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', 
               16, -- Severity.  
               1 -- State.  
               );  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    -- RAISE ERROR en bloque catch para forzar la devolución de error personalizado
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
               @ErrorState -- State.  
               );  
END CATCH;
```

**Notas importantes**

> - Las funciones del sistema **ERROR_LINE**, **ERROR_MESSAGE**, **ERROR_NUMBER**,
>     **ERROR_PROCEDURE**, **ERROR_SEVERITY**, **ERROR_STATE** y **@@ERROR** informan de los
>     valores especificados por **RAISERROR**. Cuando se ejecuta **RAISERROR** con
>     un nivel de gravedad 11 o superior en un bloque `TRY`, transfiere el
>     control al bloque `CATCH` asociado. El error se devuelve al autor de la
>     llamada si **RAISERROR** se ejecuta
> - **RAISERROR** se puede utilizar como alternativa a **PRINT** para devolver
>     mensajes a las aplicaciones que realizan llamadas. La sustitución de
>     caracteres que **RAISERROR** admite es similar a la de la función `printf`
>     de la biblioteca de C estándar, mientras que no sucede lo mismo con la
>     instrucción **PRINT** de Transact-SQL. La instrucción **PRINT** no se ve
>     afectada por los bloques TRY, mientras que, si **RAISERROR** se ejecuta
>     con un nivel de gravedad de 11 a 19 en un bloque **TRY**, transfiere el
>     control al bloque **CATCH** asociado. Especifique un nivel de gravedad 10
>     o inferior para que **RAISERROR** devuelva un mensaje desde un bloque **TRY**
>     sin invocar el bloque **CATCH**.
> - El argumento **'State'** puede contener valores entre `0 - 255` y se emplea
>     para generar marcas que ayuden a identificar el origen del error que
>     se desea generar.

Comment: Gracias, ¡muy bien explicado!